# Changing texts/pictures of buttons

Tags: android

For custom buttons, what code to use to change the text/picture of that button. For example, I click the button once the picture changes to one thing and I click it again, the picture changes to to something else. How do I do that?

Comment: From where are you getting images?? Share some code or any Screen shot for more details

Comment: I made the images using photoshop. I have no code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int i=0;
btnRes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(i%2==0){
    btnRes.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mypic);
i++;
}
else
{
btnRes.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourpic);
i++;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Parijat Bose! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background of a button by using a selector xml, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_active"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_pressed"
      android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_focused" />
</selector>
```

You can put these in the Drawable folder of your project.

And you can change the text of a button on a click event by setting it in the button's onClickListener.

Comment: Nope, if you want something like that, use a ToggleButton, or do the changes programatically in the Button's onClickListener